# Installing Office365 with wine probelm

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, office365

I'm trying to install Office365 with wine.
I get this error

[image: error message]
I have more than 60GB of free storage space and my internet is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office365 does not work with Wine (nor PlayOnLinux). You can get the older versions working, such as Office 2007 and Office 2010, but that’s about it.

There are generally two options available for people who want to use the Office tools on Linux:

1. Try to install them via [CrossOver](https://www.codeweavers.com/crossover), a paid application that claims to run Microsoft software well on multiple platforms
2. Use the web version of Office 365

I’ve been doing the second option for a couple of years now with increasing success. If you run the online version from the Edge beta, you’ll find that everything “just works” for the most part, with only an occasional need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

While this isn’t the answer you’re looking for, I hope it helps